# How to solve this geometry problem on circle

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

I've tried to solve this and got $25$. But i don't trust that it's true answer. I've exam tomorrow so if someone helps, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m(DBE)=x=m(EAD)$ {because angle which subtend same arcs are equal)

$m(AEB)=90$ {AB is the diameter and angle subtended by diameter is 90}

$m(DAB)=m(DEB)=40$ {angles which subtend same arcs are equal}

Therefore, $m(AED)=m(AEB)+m(BED)=40+90=130$

$m(CEA)=180-130=50$ {linear pair axiom}

$m(CAE)=180-{m(ECA)+m(CEA)}=180-75=105$

$m(EAB)=180-105=75$ {linear pair axiom}

$m(EAD)=75-40=35=x$

Proved.

Comment: Thanks for everything. it needed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

(1) Find $\angle CDA$ by considering $\triangle ACD$

(2) $\angle ABE=\angle CDA$

(3) $\angle ADB=90^\circ$

(4) Find $x$.

The answer is $35^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks. i've founded true answer.

Answer (score 0):

i have $$25^{\circ}+50^{\circ}+90^{\circ}+50^{\circ}-x=180^{\circ}$$ therefore $$x=35^{\circ}$$
the natural numbers are to difficult for me

Comment: Nope, sorry ... .

Comment: Starting at $m(DCB)$ and going clockwise, I've got $25^{\circ} + 15^{\circ} + 90^{\circ} + x  + 15^{\circ} = 180^{\circ} \implies x = 35^{\circ} $

Comment: yes of Course, i have had a simple mistake $$40^{\circ}+90^{\circ}+70^{\circ}=180^{\circ}$$ in my calculations it is to hot for me here

Comment: Thanks. i've founded true answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\measuredangle EBA=\measuredangle EDA=40^{\circ}-25^{\circ}=15^{\circ}.$$
Thus,
$$x=50^{\circ}-15^{\circ}=35^{\circ}$$

Comment: Thanks. i've founded true answer.

Comment: @Physicer You are welcome!